# How do I draw thick lines with closely spaced points properly with Java2D graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d, shapes

I'm trying to draw maps using Java2D. When my map is zoomed out my roads are full of drawing artefacts. This is a small part of the screen when drawing a complete US state:

[image: Road section drawn at state scale showing drawing artefacts]

This is a similar section of the road when zoomed closer in:

[image: Road section drawn at sub-county scale with no drawing artefacts]

The line style used is a solid blue line with width scaled to be equivalent to 2 pixels.
I've tried various rendering hints and line joining rules and nothing seems to help.

I'm using Open JDK 1.7 on a Mac running the OS/X 10.8 and this is also reproducible on a Linux machine with a Sun JDK 1.6.

All shapes and transforms are double precision as far as possible with Java2D.
The geometry of the line has many closely spaced points and I suspect that the cause of the drawing artefacts is that the renderer is getting confused by consecutive points that are closer than a single pixel.

Is there a way to improve the appearance of the zoomed out shapes without thinning the points?

**Edit**
The drawing artefacts are at the points where separate line segments meet, so the missing pixels are something to do with the line caps (ends) not meeting, even when the end points are identical. This image shows the meeting point between two line segments. I have highlighted each line segment in a 7 pixel scaled line style (XOR-ed with white) but if you look very closely you can still see part of the original blue line (this is due to the rounded caps overlapping and the XOR draw mode.) At ordinary scales the ends seem to overlap, but when zoomed out and back in ordinary paint mode there is a broken line effect.

One workaround would be to join all the contiguous line segments together before drawing them, but I would still like to know the real cause of the drawing artefacts.

[image: Join between two road segments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to recreate the situation you have using the OS X 1.6 JDK, but I still have some suggestions for you.

If you are just using this to outline states, consider using the [`GeneralPath` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html). You can use the `lineTo(x,y)` method to establish each of your points on the line. Again, because I can't recreate your problem using `Line2D.Double`, I don't know if this will actually be any different.

Second, and possibly more importantly, is how you are zooming in and out. I am using an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) (with `setScaleTo(x,y)`) on my `Graphics2D` object, and everything is working swimmingly. Compared to the alternative of scaling the points in your data by a zoom factor (or whatever else you could do), this is fairly easy. You'll also have to adjust the stroke of the lines by the factor, because it will scale everything down. I can post screenshots if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using an AffineTransform which is a combination of scale and translate operations. I am also scaling the stroke width. Some of my coordinates are 5 - 10m apart. The full width of the canvas when zoomed out is about 1,000,000m. I will see if I can roll back to an old version of the code that runs with the Apple 1.6 JDK. I mainly see the problem when drawing roads. County boundaries seem fine but probably don't have the same level of detail.

Comment: I also see the problem with the Apple JDK 1.6. I'm starting to wonder if the problem is not related to drawing artefacts within a line, but at the end-points of the line segments. Looking closely at the data the roads are not long continuous lines with many vertices, but many shorter line segments with contiguous end-points.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it eventually led me to the solution. I either have to turn off one of my drawing optimizations for this layer or join the segments together for each highway.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) it should answer you question!

Basic Concept

```
function plot(x, y, c) is
plot the pixel at (x, y) with brightness c (where 0 ≤ c ≤ 1)

function ipart(x) is
return integer part of x

function round(x) is
return ipart(x + 0.5)

function fpart(x) is
return fractional part of x

function rfpart(x) is
return 1 - fpart(x)

function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2) is
dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1
if abs(dx) < abs(dy) then                 
  swap x1, y1
  swap x2, y2
  swap dx, dy
end if
if x2 < x1
  swap x1, x2
  swap y1, y2
end if
gradient = dy / dx

// handle first endpoint
xend = round(x1)
yend = y1 + gradient * (xend - x1)
xgap = rfpart(x1 + 0.5)
xpxl1 = xend  // this will be used in the main loop
ypxl1 = ipart(yend)
plot(xpxl1, ypxl1, rfpart(yend) * xgap)
plot(xpxl1, ypxl1 + 1, fpart(yend) * xgap)
intery = yend + gradient // first y-intersection for the main loop

// handle second endpoint
xend = round (x2)
yend = y2 + gradient * (xend - x2)
xgap = fpart(x2 + 0.5)
xpxl2 = xend  // this will be used in the main loop
ypxl2 = ipart (yend)
plot (xpxl2, ypxl2, rfpart (yend) * xgap)
plot (xpxl2, ypxl2 + 1, fpart (yend) * xgap)

// main loop
for x from xpxl1 + 1 to xpxl2 - 1 do
    plot (x, ipart (intery), rfpart (intery))
    plot (x, ipart (intery) + 1, fpart (intery))
    intery = intery + gradient
end function
```

Comment: +1 for the algorithm, in particular the link on Wikipedia that says "Lines less than one pixel long should be handled as a special case." The article would be even more relevant if it explained exactly how to handle this special case as the question specifically alludes to sub-pixel line segments as a possible cause of the artefacts. I would expect low level rendering algorithms to be implemented in the Java2D API. The solution that I'm looking for will either explain how to use the Java2D API to achieve a continuous, thickened line. Thank you for an informative reply.

Comment: Another acceptable solution would explain why this isn't currently possible and supply a workaround better than the one proposed in the question (point thinning before rendering the shape.)