# Java DrawLine With Stroke Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, drawing, line

I know the algorithm for drawing a simple line, but I am having trouble finding how java creates lines with stroke. At first I thought maybe they draw a rectangle for each pixel along the line, but then I realized it could take extra time from the redrawing of already drawn pixels. The reason I would like to know this algorithm is so I can receive the pixels changed from painting.

Note: This line Algorithm is from Tech-algorithm.com

```
public void line(int x,int y,int x2, int y2, int color) {
    int w = x2 - x ;
    int h = y2 - y ;
    int dx1 = 0, dy1 = 0, dx2 = 0, dy2 = 0 ;
    if (w<0) dx1 = -1 ; else if (w>0) dx1 = 1 ;
    if (h<0) dy1 = -1 ; else if (h>0) dy1 = 1 ;
    if (w<0) dx2 = -1 ; else if (w>0) dx2 = 1 ;
    int longest = Math.abs(w) ;
    int shortest = Math.abs(h) ;
    if (!(longest>shortest)) {
        longest = Math.abs(h) ;
        shortest = Math.abs(w) ;
        if (h<0) dy2 = -1 ; else if (h>0) dy2 = 1 ;
        dx2 = 0 ;            
    }
    int numerator = longest >> 1 ;
    for (int i=0;i<=longest;i++) {
        buffer.setRGB(x, y, color);

        numerator += shortest ;
        if (!(numerator<longest)) {
            numerator -= longest ;
            x += dx1 ;
            y += dy1 ;
        } else {
            x += dx2 ;
            y += dy2 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure Java does.  I think you'll find a lot of this will be handled of to the DirectX or OpenGL layers...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would much rather try to do these algorithms myself to allow flexibility on what I can and cannot do. I much rather stick with java with this one although it may be a little more difficult than using OpenGL and DirectX.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't, but if you want to know how Java does it, it's likely this information is passed down the pipeline to the native graphics layer and handled by the functionality provided by those APIs...just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, so if I were to look at the source code on these two API's, assuming much of the source is not already compiled, I can recreate what I want based on what OpenGL and DirectX has to offer?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: [SO: How do I draw thick lines with closely spaced points properly with Java2D graphics?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11953245/1762224). User [Aeshang](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1085186/aeshang) provides a link to [WP: Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Much like the Bresenham algorithm I used for drawing the line provided from tech-algorithm.com the Xiaolin algorithm only provides for lined without stroke i.e. only 1 pixel wide. I am looking for something that will stroke the line making it thicker.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a simple-ish modification?